# Is this a correct way to express $\left|f(x)\right| \leq \left|x\right|^9$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

If $\left|f(x)\right| \leq \left|x\right|^9$, then, is it correct to say that

$f(x) \leq x^9$ and $f(x) \geq -x^9$ ?

If it is not, could someone explain why? Thank you.

Comment: $x$ might be negative?

Comment: Mark has it exactly right - if $x$ is not negative, you are correct that this is equivalent. But the use of $\left|x\right|$ implies that $x$ might be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on what Mark Bennet said, your formulation is almost correct: it's not $-x^9\leq f(x)\leq x^9$, but it is $-|x|^9\leq f(x)\leq |x|^9$.

To get rid of the absolute values *entirely* takes some care, but it can be done. The expression is the same as the piecewise expression
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
-x^9\leq f(x)\leq x^9 &: x>0 \\
-x^9\geq f(x)\geq x^9 &: x<0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
which can be phrased using OR: Either $-x^9\leq f(x)\leq x^9>0~$ OR $~-x^9\geq f(x)\geq x^9 <0$. There's no really good reason to write something this silly, but if you need it in a particular form for reasons, this is one possibility.

Comment: Could you please explain how the inequality |f(x)| <= |x|^9 becomes -|x|^9 <= f(x) <= |x|^9 ? This whole absolute value concept has always confused me :/

Comment: Yeah, no problem. If $|a|\leq d$ then intuitively we think of $d$ as a distance, and $a$ can be no further from $0$ than $d$. This means that $a\leq d$, but also $-a\leq d$. Putting these together gives what I wrote. (To do this rigorously, you can use the definition: $|x|$ is $x$ if $x\geq 0$ or $-x$ if $x<0$.)

Answer (score 0):

I would call this somewhat silly and write it as

$$between(-|x|^n, f(x), |x|^9)$$